# Java Generic method for accept any class and return data?

Tags: java, java-8

In Spring Batch code, while writing batchUpdate I have added exception handling, in case of any records failed I am handling with the below logic which works fine. But I've around 70 writer in my project and I wanted to make a generic method for the below code and at run time pass the Employee, Department, Student, Stock etc class and get the details back.

How can I do that ?

```
private List<Employee> getFailedRecords(Exception e, List<? extends Employee> items, Map<Integer, String> map){
    List<Employee> data = new ArrayList<>();
    if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
        BatchUpdateException be = (BatchUpdateException) e.getCause();
        int[] batchRes = be.getUpdateCounts();
        if (batchRes != null && batchRes.length > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < batchRes.length; index++) {
                if (batchRes[index] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                    data.add(items.get(index));
                    map.put(index, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make the method generic:

```
private <T> List<T> getFailedRecords(Exception e, List<? extends T> items, 
        Map<Integer, String> map) {
    
    List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();
    
    if (e.getCause() instanceof BatchUpdateException) {
        BatchUpdateException be = (BatchUpdateException) e.getCause();
        int[] batchRes = be.getUpdateCounts();
        if (batchRes != null && batchRes.length > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < batchRes.length; index++) {
                if (batchRes[index] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
                    data.add(items.get(index));
                    map.put(index, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Unless the bounded wildcard is necessary (such as when you need to pass a list of subclasses of `Employee`/`Student`, etc.), you should be able to dispense with it, and type the second parameter as `List<T>`.